# how to save and open variables to a file using tkFileDialog?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to save few variables in a file using tkFileDialog save option.  and in later part i have to retrieve the same variables. i am not getting any idea how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Please, can you specify  what do you mean by "save few variables"? Writing its values in a XML/JSON document? Storing them in a database?

Comment: no i am not using database, xml/json. i am trying to save in some csv or txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pickle:

```
import tkFileDialog
filename = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
a = 1
b = []
c = {}
f = open(filename, 'wb') # wb is important
import pickle
pickle.dump((a,b,c), f)
f.close()
```

Now load:

```
import tkFileDialog
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
f = open(filename, 'rb') # rb is important
import pickle
a, b, c = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: when i tried to use ur above code to save i am getting this error TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: I tried the code again and got no error, to help you, I need more information.

Comment: pickle is easy and you can store a lot of python objects. if you want to use something else: try `import json` or use a combination of `repr` and `eval`. There are more possibilities. Why don't you want to use pickle?